# Flask problem p://ip/static/css/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)

Tags: python, flask

```
I get this error    p://myip/static/css/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)
in python flask please tell me how to fix it 

Flask:    https://pastebin.com/8za6M7L5
Signup:    https://pastebin.com/pdLRsymV
Login:    https://pastebin.com/CrWGhFMe
Main/Index:    https://pastebin.com/8Pt5tUmr
Cooperation:    https://pastebin.com/ZuZfSqDZ

The explainision of the code:
```

Flask: app.py or mainfile in python
Login: Still working on that but this is gonna be for login
Signup: Still working but this is for new users to signup
Main/Index: Index.html or Main.html
Cooperation: Still working but this is a html to users co cooperation with our team

```
The name and the path are good i dont know what the problem is


Changing name, Changing path, I even used chatgpt for the first time to look my code and it says that the         code is fine
```

Comment: can u share your index html

Comment: @PouryaMohamadiI arleady did Main/Index:    https://pastebin.com/8Pt5tUmr